# typescript-eslint checking if all variables are assigned a data type

Tags: typescript, eslint, typechecking

Is there a way to check if all variables in my code have a data type assigned to them using eslint-typescript? For example, `const a = 1;` shouldn't be allowed and eslint should throw an error. `const a:number = 1` is allowed

Comment: Did you read the list of rules to see?

Comment: Yes. But I didn't find any that followed this scenario

Comment: Then does that answer your question? Note that it has the _opposite_ rule, preventing inferable types (an explicit type for a const is pretty pointless).

Comment: What is the opposite rule?

Comment: https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/master/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/no-inferrable-types.md